# Tensorflow : slice index of dimension out of bounds

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use the following code, when I execute it on a raspberry pi I get this error :

```
2022-03-12 10:13:08.979777: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafael/companion.py", line 109, in <module>
    for spectrogram, label in sample_ds.batch(1):
  File "/home/rafael/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7107, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index  of dimension  out of bounds.
         [[{{node strided_slice}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

When I run it on colab.research.google.com, it works.

Here is the code used :

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

commands = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def preprocess_dataset(files):
  files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
  output_ds = files_ds.map(
      map_func=get_waveform_and_label,
      num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  output_ds = output_ds.map(
      map_func=get_spectrogram_and_label_id,
      num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  return output_ds

MODEL_PATH = 'my_model_1.h5'

# Recreate the exact same model, including its weights and the optimizer
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)

# Show the model architecture
new_model.summary()

sample_file = 'test.wav'

sample_ds = preprocess_dataset([str(sample_file)])

for spectrogram, label in sample_ds.batch(1):
  prediction = new_model(spectrogram)
  plt.bar(commands, tf.nn.softmax(prediction[0]))
  plt.title(f'Predictions for "{commands[label[0]]}"')
  plt.show()
```

I don't know if it comes from my code, or from my tensorflow installation on my Raspberry Pi. If you have a suggestion

Comment: it will be the `tensorflow` installation on the `Raspberry Pi`.

Comment: Thanks, I will redo the installation differently